# i need to create a sequential approval workflow in Sharepoint Designer 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

I need to create a sequential  approval workflow in Sharepoint Designer 2010 where Approve 2 can approve  only when Approver 1 has approved it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use **`Wait`** condition to wait until the `Approval Status` to be equal `0;#Approved`, then start the second Approve process.

[image]

Comment: the second step(wait for approval) is it there in actions ??

Comment: Yes, it's action in both WF 2010/2013,